# nautilus-compare (meld integration with nautilus) and other nautilus-actions-extra packages not working with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, diff, nautilus-extensions

I had nautilus-compare (and other nautilus-actions-extra packages) perfectly working with Ubuntu 12.04

I've just did a fresh install of Ubuntu raring ringtail, and then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install meld nautilus-compare
nautilus -q
```

but the extra context menu(s) doesn't show up

Has anybody else had this trouble? In that case where should I file this bug?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the bug report.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-compare/+bug/1172953

**Which suggests this WORKAROUND:**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so /usr/lib/libpython.2.7.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/libpython.2.7.so.1
sudo ldconfig
# fresh login or reboot of machine may be needed here
nautilus
```

Note:

- If `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so` doesn't exist, replace that line with:

  `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/libpython.2.7.so`
- If `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1` doesn't exist, replace that line with:

  `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so /usr/lib/libpython.2.7.so.1`

**In deed, this also re-enables all other *Nautilus Actions Extra* context menu items that stopped working with nautilus-compare.**

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug in nautilus-python - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-python/+bug/1170017

fixed in 13.10 but not for 13.04 yet (or ever.

For 13.04 one can do the symlinks or a repaired nautilus-python package for 13.04 is available here - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/n-p-testfix